# My folder of Django rest framework is in terms of plain text instead of .python what can I do?

Tags: django-rest-framework

[My folder of Django rest framework is in terms of plain text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW4Xr.jpg)

I tried to reinstall and restart my VS code and still nothing came out, i also tried to update my vs code but my VS code is up to date. I expect a positive outcome.